# In Selenium IDE, can I use wildcards with the type command?

Tags: xpath, selenium, ide

I am new to Selenium IDE, which has been tremendously helpful in my testing, but I have run into a snag.  I am trying to enter a fake credit card number in my company's testing environment (e-commerce company), but the XPath changes each time I go back to the page.  The path is below.

```
//*[@id="dwfrm_paymentinstruments_creditcards_newcreditcard_number_d0hnrobkriuu"]
```

`d0hnrobkriuu` is what changes each time.  I tried the following alternatives -

```
//*[@id="dwfrm_paymentinstruments_creditcards_newcreditcard_number_*"]
//*[@id="dwfrm_paymentinstruments_creditcards_newcreditcard_number_[a-zA-Z0-9]"]
```

According to various selenium documentation I have found, those globbing techniques should work, but they're not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not this way, no. But, using the XPath [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function, you can do

```
//*[contains(@id, "dwfrm_paymentinstruments_creditcards_newcreditcard_number_")]
```

Comment: kroe761 - it is common practice to check an answer as "correct" if it solves your problem. That way all other readers know that it was answered correctly, and the author gets some points too.

Comment: Better late than never :-)