# Selenium IDE, using wildcard characters in target using name= and id=

Tags: selenium, ide

I am new to selenium and even newer to programming languages.  I am creating a test scenario for my company's customer service software (we sell magazine subscriptions).  Problem is, certain fields have varying names and identifiers in the target.  Two examples -

```
id=address_menu_71736039

name=auto_renew_47457811
```

The numbers are changing each time.  I posted a question previously regarding xpath, but this code seems to be simpler and that trick won't work).  Any ideas?  I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You can find the anwer at below page. It worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545468/in-selenium-ide-can-i-use-wildcards-with-the-type-command